# Call function in handle submit with typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to call a function on handle submit, it responds correctly when I'm not trying to call my another function and it returns me the next error:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.btnSubmit is undefined

so my handle submit have is the next on my ts:

```
handleOk(): void {
      console.log('Button ok clicked!');
      this.AddTeam();
      // this.isVisible = false;
    }
```

it is calling to AddTeam, and AddTeam haves the next structure:

```
async AddTeam(){
      let Toast;
      try {
        const NewTeam =
        {
          Name: this.formAddTeam.value.TeamName,
          UserId: this.currentUser.UserId,
          CompanyId: this.currentCompany.CompanyId,
          ColorMark: this.formAddTeam.value.ColorMarkerTeam
        };
        const UserIds = [
        {
          UserId: this.currentUser.UserId
        }
      ];

        const Team = {
        Team: NewTeam,
        Users: UserIds
        };

        const result: ResponseModel =  await this._team.AddTeam(Team).toPromise();

      } catch (error) {
      }
    }
```

Why it throws me that error? if you need more information pleas ask for them

Comment: It seems to me the code causing the error is not included in the code, Look for `this.btnSubmit` in your code.

Comment: @SherifElmetainy I think is something that happend when I call another function, if I put the code of AddTeam into HandleOk instead of call it, it works. Also this.submit is not included in my code, it could be something predefined in angular